# ffmpeg: disable transparent in all gif frames

Tags: ffmpeg, transparency

with FFMPEG, I try to disable transparent mode for all frames in gif, from png files.
I tried many options in FFMPEG, but with my many tests, I only get the first frame to be transparent disable, all others are transparent enable.
I can check each frame of my gif file with the website https://onlinegiftools.com/analyze-gif

my actual solution I found is to add a palette for each frame with option reserve_transparent=0 for each palette, but the gif file is bigger than with a global palette :

ffmpeg -v error -framerate 15 -i frame%05d.png -filter_complex "[0:v] split [a][b];[a] palettegen=max_colors=64:reserve_transparent=0:stats_mode=single [p];[b][p] paletteuse=new=1" -y animation.gif

with FFMPEG, how to disable transparent from png for all frames in gif, with a global palettegen for all frames?

best regards from france.

Comment: hello Rotem. thanks for the suggestion, I did try your three lines, the generated gif file has got the same problem as my first tests (checked with online analyse-gif), only the first frame is "transparent: false", all other frames in gif are "transparent: true". so, my solution to disable transparent mode on each palette for each frame is the only way I found. I don't want black as transparent color, I just need to disable transparent on each frame.

Comment: if you import your generated gif (nyT3G.gif) in https://onlinegiftools.com/analyze-gif you will see that problem for transparency in frames.

Comment: Can you please respond to my answer? Did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following stages:

- Create a tile PNG image that constrains scaled version of all the input images:
  The tile is used for generating a global palette that is based on all the images (instead of only single image). The tile background is transparent.
  [I couldn't find a better option for creating global palette].

  ```
   ffmpeg -y -i frame%05d.png -vf "scale=120:-1,tile=10x10:color=black@0" -frames:v 1 tmp.png
  ```
- Use `palettegen` for generating a palette (from the tile):

  ```
   ffmpeg -y -i tmp.png -vf "palettegen=max_colors=64:reserve_transparent=0:stats_mode=single" palette.png
  ```
- Apply the palette using `paletteuse`:
  [It is possible to merge the two last commands].

  ```
   ffmpeg -y -framerate 15 -i frame%05d.png -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse animation.gif
  ```

---

I tested it using frames from the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70540761/ffmpeg-alpha-channel-video-generation).

Result:
[image]

Tile:
[image]

---

The background color of the result is not well defined.

We may set it to black for example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i frame%05d.png -vf "format=rgb24,scale=120:-1,tile=10x10:color=black" -frames:v 1 tmp.png
ffmpeg -y -i tmp.png -vf "palettegen=max_colors=64:reserve_transparent=0:stats_mode=single" palette.png
ffmpeg -y -framerate 15 -i frame%05d.png -i palette.png -filter_complex "[0]format=rgb24[b];[b][1]paletteuse=new=1" animation.gif
```

---

Result:
[image]